# decaying of `char` array when passed into a function

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code

```
auto print_name(char* name) -> void
{
    printf("Name: %s", name);
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char name[300] = "Uncle Roger";
    print_name(name);
}
```

The output I get is `Name: Uncle Roger`

I am left a bit confused as my understanding is that the char array decomposes to the pointer to the first element, in this case the char `U`, and while undergoing said decomposition, it loses the size. How come the `printf` function accurately prints the whole char array?

Is this special because char arrays are null terminated?

Comment: Yes, `printf("Name: %s", name);` expects a `NUL` terminated array.

Comment: "*Is this special because char arrays are null terminated?*" - no, arrays (char or otherwise) are not terminated. **string literals**, on the other hand, ARE null-terminated. You are simply copying the string literal's terminator into your array, and then `printf()` stops outputting when it reaches that terminator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this special because char arrays are null terminated?

That's exactly what's going on. If the array had not been terminated by a `'\0'` character, `printf` would continue to read out of bounds, with undefined behavior as a result.

---

The fact that the assumed null terminated strings may sometimes *not* be null terminated (by a programmer mistake) has made an impact on some library writers, so certain functions that previously accepted `const char*` have been removed and in their place, only `char` arrays with a known bound are accepted.

Your function could for example be rewritten like so:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
void print_name(const char(&name)[N]) {
    constexpr int max_len = static_cast<int>(N);
    static_assert(max_len > 0, "invalid string length");

    printf("Name: %.*s\n", max_len, name); // don't read more than max_len chars
}
```

And it'd work even if the array was not null terminated:

```cpp
int main() {
    char name[2] = {'H','i'};
    print_name(name);
}
```

... and it'd refuse a naked `const char*`:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto& ref = "Hello";   // const char(&ref)[6] = "Hello";
    auto ptr = "World";    // const char* ptr = "World";
    
    print_name("Testing"); // ok
    print_name(ref);       // ok
    // print_name(ptr);    // error
}
```